# Can I use only left swipe for UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete and make right swipe gesture respons to another method?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm using UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete in my project.
Now both the left and right swip gesture will active the delete button.

I want only the left swipe gesture to active the delete button, and make right swipe gesture to response to another method(to pop viewController).

How can I implement this?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your own custom UIGestureRecognizers, perhaps to the view of a UITableViewCell subclass, instead of using the built-in behaviors of UITableView.

Comment: Thanks. I added a right-swpite gesture recognizer to the tableView and     it works.

Comment: Hey @Max can you tell me how you did that...... and is actions are default or you added custom views behind custom cell?